# Broken dependencies with texlive

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, texlive

I had a working version of texlive on 16.04 but after updating from 16.04 to 16.10 and then to 17.04 (and maybe other things?) it's now broken. I've purged all of my texlive packages with apt-get : `sudo apt-get purge tex*`
I've also purged all of my texlive in dpkg `sudo dpkg --purge texlive` for all of texlive and related packages. All of the following run with no errors:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

But when I try to install texlive I get:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done  
Some packages could not be installed.  
This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are  
using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created    
or been moved out of Incoming.  
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 texlive : Depends: texlive-latex-recommended (>= 2016) but it is not going to be installed  
           Depends: texlive-latex-base (>= 2016) but it is not going to be installed  
           Depends: texlive-fonts-recommended (>= 2016) but it is not going to be installed  
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Ubuntu 16.10 is no longer supported. Please upgrade to 17.04.

Comment: OK I have upgraded to 17.04 and the same issue persists.

Answer (score 3):

OK after trying some more things for a while I installed aptitude which was able propose a solution (after trying the first one and failing) that worked, downgrading `libpathsea6`. Details:

```
oz@oz-linux:~$ sudo aptitude install texlive-latex-base
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-lmodern{a} libpotrace0{a} libptexenc1{a} libsynctex1{a} libtexlua52{a} libtexluajit2{a} libzzip-0-13{a} lmodern{a} 
  texlive-base{a} texlive-binaries{ab} texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-base-doc{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 12 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 83.4 MB of archives. After unpacking 188 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 texlive-binaries : Depends: libkpathsea6 (< 2016.20160513.41080.dfsg-1.1~) but 2017.20170613.44585-1~16.04.york0 is installed
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     texlive-base [Not Installed]                       
2)     texlive-binaries [Not Installed]                   
3)     texlive-latex-base [Not Installed]                 
4)     texlive-latex-base-doc [Not Installed]             


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

 Downgrade the following packages:                                                             
 1)     libkpathsea6 [2017.20170613.44585-1~16.04.york0 (now) -> 2016.20160513.41080.dfsg-1 (zesty)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and what I did was : `sudo apt-get purge texlive`  and then run `sudo apt-get autoremove` and the sequence of fix install commands you have mentioned and then the command:

`sudo apt-get install texlive-full`

Comment: Tried this previously, still get the same error messages.